# RadGrid - How do you change HeaderText of Bound field?

Tags: asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid

I am using a RadGrid and I had the autogenerated set to true. This results in a column header text of the the database field cap_name. In an ASP.NET GridView you would change it like (after setting autogeneratedcolumns to false:

```
<Columns>
         <asp:BoundField DataField="cap_name" HeaderText="Capability" 
            SortExpression="cap_name" />
    </Columns>
```

I set autogenerated colums to false and tried to use BoundField but the compiler said to use telerik:GridColumn. How do I use this to get a similar result?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, as a new user to the stackoverflow, don't forget to accept and optionally upvote the answer/any answer that you think it solves your problem or helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `<rad:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="Capability" UniqueName="ClmCapability" DataField="cap_name" />` .

**NOTE :** replace `<rad:` with the prefix you use for your RadGrid control when you register it. You can find it as **TagPrefix** in :

```
<%@ Register Assembly="RadGrid.Net2" Namespace="Telerik.WebControls" TagPrefix="rad" %>
```

You can't use `asp:boundfield` because it is for asp.net gridview, while you are using telerik radgrid

EDIT :

```
<rad:RadGrid ID="MyRadGrid" runat="server" EnableAJAXLoadingTemplate="true"  
            AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowFilteringByColumn="True" AllowPaging="True"
            AllowSorting="True" GridLines="None" Width="60%" EnableAJAX="True" OnNeedDataSource="MyRadGrid_NeedDataSource">
            <ClientSettings AllowColumnsReorder="True" ReorderColumnsOnClient="True">
            </ClientSettings>
            <MasterTableView RetrieveAllDataFields="false" AdditionalDataFieldNames="Name">
                <PagerStyle AlwaysVisible="false" Mode="NextPrevNumericAndAdvanced" ShowPagerText="true" />
                <Columns>

                    <rad:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="Capability" UniqueName="ClmCapability" DataField="cap_name" />

                </Columns>
            </MasterTableView>
        </rad:RadGrid>
```

Comment: Error 1 Type 'Telerik.Web.UI.RadGrid' does not have a public property named 'GridBoundColumn'. C:\dev\RIC\AutomotiveServicesRIC\AutomotiveServicesRIC\branches\RICQ32013_OKL_3000\admin\EditCapabilities.aspx 15

Comment: I solved by just changing the query to return what name I wanted:

    SELECT v2Capabilities.cap_name AS Capability FROM v2Capabilities ORDER BY v2Capabilities.cap_name

Comment: That works, but not what you asked :) and btw you are using the GridBound column in the wrong place :) Check my edit

Comment: Thank you :) Hope it benefits you